# PYTHON downloading google drive spreadsheet

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to use python to access the google api for downloading spreadsheet from google drive, I borrow the code from google api examples and did some change to it. However, Everytime I run , I always have this httpError return saying that I have "Insufficient Permission".  I have attached my code below and I am wondering if anyone could have a look at it and let me know which part is wrong.  Thanks

```
import httplib2
import os
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
import io

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive API Python Quickstart'

def get_credentials():

    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'drive-python-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():

    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
    file_id = '1tRL7q2AYdQuuaWQyfT700H3WG6Klod9EtjF2yTMoGiE'
    request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
                                                 mimeType='text/csv')
    fh = io.FileIO('LISAtrial.csv')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the permission of the user to access the file. In the [*Handling API Errors*](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/handle-errors) Document of Google Drive API V3,

> **403: Insufficient file permissions. The user does not have sufficient permissions for file {fileId}.**

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "insufficientFilePermissions",
"message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for file {fileId}."
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for file {fileId}."
}
}
```

> You may also want to check user access levels in the metadata retrieved by [*files.get*](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) and use that to change your UI to a read only UI.

User permission and improper use of [Scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#what_scope_or_scopes_does_my_app_need) may result to `Insufficient Permission` response.

Here are some related SO question:

- [Google API Insufficient Permissions listing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759610/google-api-insufficient-permissions-listing-files?rq=1)
- [Google PHP Client API: Insufficient Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896018/google-php-client-api-insufficient-permission?noredirect=1&lq=1)