# Google Drive API - Javascript - 403 The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-drive-realtime-api

I am using Google Drive API and my web app was working for over a year ago until a few days ago, I keep getting this error in my console:

It gave me a url in my log, after opening it, it shows this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions",
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
 }
}
```

I keep getting this error along with this in my console:

```
{result: {…}, body: "{↵ "error": {↵  "errors": [↵   {↵    "domain": "gl…,↵  "code": 400,↵  "message": "Bad Request"↵ }↵}↵", headers: {…}, status: 400, statusText: null}
body
:
"{↵ "error": {↵  "errors": [↵   {↵    "domain": "global",↵    "reason": "badRequest",↵    "message": "Bad Request"↵   }↵  ],↵  "code": 400,↵  "message": "Bad Request"↵ }↵}↵
```

"

I have looked at [Google's Error Handling Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors)as well as other answers on here. However, I am not able to resolve this despite asking for full drive permission in scopes through Scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive. All I need to do is get access to listing and deleting the files, I am not sure why I don't have permissions all of a sudden despite this working for over a year.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you try generating new credentials? Also, check if this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759610/google-api-insufficient-permissions-listing-files)